# Fill between on top of axis background

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

How can I draw the fill between area on top of another fill area that is drawn in the axis background preaction?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2}]
        \nextgroupplot[
            grid,
            axis background/.style={%
                preaction={
                    path picture={
                        \fill [black!5] (axis cs:2,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
        \addplot[name path=path1] table {
            0 0
            1 1
            2 2
            3 3
            4 5
        };
        \addplot[name path=path2] table {
            0 1
            1 2
            2 3
            3 4
            4 6
        };
        \addplot[fill=red, forget plot, fill opacity=0.25] fill between[of=path1 and path2];

        \nextgroupplot[
            grid,
            axis background/.style={%
                preaction={
                    path picture={
                        \fill [black!5] (axis cs:8,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
   \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found that adding `set layers, cell picture=true` fixes the issue:

[image]

Comment: Where do you add "set layers, cell picture=true" ?