# How to draw a figure behind the axis with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

I have this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=center,xmin=-1,xmax=9,ymin=-1,ymax=9,line width=0.4mm]
        \pgfplotsset{xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$}}
        \draw[fill=blue!40,line width=0mm] (5,-0.5) rectangle (8,0.5);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Rectangle forward of the figure]

I try adding `on layer=axis background` to the `draw` command, but unfortunately it does not work because it must be inside to the `addplot` command.

I do not want to put the rectangle in the `tikzpicture` environment, because that forces me to change the values of where it is. Is there any way to put a figure (rectangle, circle, etc.) within the `axis` environment and that is behind the axes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Axis background seems to work, I also added a simple way to smuggle coordinates outside the axis environment, even though it is not needed here. BTW, depending on your plot, you may want to add [`set layers, cell picture=true`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231127/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=center,xmin=-1,xmax=9,ymin=-1,ymax=9,line
    width=0.4mm, axis background/.style={%
                preaction={
                    path picture={
                        \draw[fill=blue!40,line width=0mm] (axis cs:5,-0.5) rectangle (axis cs:8,0.5);
                    }}}]
        \pgfplotsset{xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$}}
        \coordinate (BL) at (5,-0.5);
        \coordinate (TR) at (8,0.5); % just to export the coordinates outside
%the axis, not needed here
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked. I'm going to investigate about `set layers, cell picture = true` `:)`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `axis on top` option.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=center,xmin=-1,xmax=9,ymin=-1,ymax=9,line width=0.4mm, axis on top]
        \pgfplotsset{xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$}}
        \draw[fill=blue!40,line width=0mm] (5,-0.5) rectangle (8,0.5);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with rectangle behind axis]

Comment: Simpler `\documentclass[tikz,border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
    \begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
label={$x$},    ylabel={$y$},
xmin=-1,xmax=9, ymin=-1,ymax=9,
line width=0.4mm, 
axis on top]
        \draw[thin, fill=blue!40] (5,-0.5) rectangle (8,0.5);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`. Anyway, '1 for use of `axis on top`.

Comment: @Zarko: Yes - I just copied code from OP, and focused on the question. I did not spot the superfluous `\pgfplotsset` for the labels