# Stacked ybar interval

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to draw 2 bar plots stacked on top of each other. I have successfully been able to plot a single ybar plot as:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}                                                    
\usepackage[top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,left=2.75cm,right=2.75cm]{geometry}         
\usepackage{tikz}                                                                
\usetikzlibrary{calc}                                                            
\usepackage{pgfplots}                                                            
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}                                                 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}                                                        
                                                                                 
\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}                                                   
0 10000                                                                          
1 15000                                                                          
2 10000                                                                          
3 20000                                                                          
4 5000                                                                           
5 0                                                                              
\end{filecontents}                                                               
\begin{filecontents}{data2.txt}                                                  
0 10000                                                                          
1 15000                                                                          
2 10000                                                                          
3 20000                                                                          
4 5000                                                                           
5 0                                                                              
\end{filecontents}                                                               
\begin{document}                                                                 
\begin{figure}[h]                                                                
    \centering                                                                   
    \begin{tikzpicture}                                                          
        \begin{axis} [                                                           
                height = \axisdefaultheight,                                     
                width = \textwidth,                                              
                xlabel = Channel,                                                
                ylabel = Counts,                                                 
                ymin = 0,                                                        
                xmin = -5,                                                       
                xmax = 260,                                                      
                xtick pos = left,                                                
                axis on top,                                                     
            ]                                                                    
            % Vertical divisions                              
            \path  (current axis.above origin) coordinate (T);                   
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,4}{                                     
                \draw[draw=black!6, name path=line#1]  (64*#1-0.5,0) -- (64*#1-0.5,0|-T);
            }                                                                    
            \path[name path=line5] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}, 0|-T);
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,2,4} {                                      
                \addplot [fill=black!6] fill between[of=line#1 and               
                line\the\numexpr#1+1\relax];                                     
            }                                                                    
                                                                                 
            \addplot[                                                            
                ybar interval,                                                   
                x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-0.5},                            
                fill = black!20] table {data.txt};                               
        \end{axis}                                                               
    \end{tikzpicture}                                                            
\end{figure}                                                                     
\end{document}
```

Which look exactly what I want for a single histogram:
[image: Good plot]

My first problem is that if I add `ybar stacked` to my `axis`, I get an error:

```
! Package pgf Error: fill between: the mandatory argument 'of=<name path A> and
 <name path B> is missing or has empty arguments. Please ensure that the option
 has been set and that both path names have been assigned (perhaps you need 'na
me path global=line4' somewhere?).

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.56            \end{axis}
```

For some reason my vertical lines don't get drawn and cause this error. I have to remove them to move one (how can I keep them?).

The second problem is that even after removing the vertical divisions (which I need to keep), I don't get the histograms to stack on top of each other:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}                                                    
\usepackage[top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,left=2.75cm,right=2.75cm]{geometry}         
\usepackage{tikz}                                                                
\usetikzlibrary{calc}                                                            
\usepackage{pgfplots}                                                            
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}                                                 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}                                                        
                                                                                 
\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}                                                   
0 10000                                                                          
1 15000                                                                          
2 10000                                                                          
3 20000                                                                          
4 5000                                                                           
5 0                                                                              
\end{filecontents}                                                               
\begin{filecontents}{data2.txt}                                                  
0 10000                                                                          
1 15000                                                                          
2 10000                                                                          
3 20000                                                                          
4 5000                                                                           
5 0                                                                              
\end{filecontents}                                                               
\begin{document}                                                                 
\begin{figure}[h]                                                                
    \centering                                                                   
    \begin{tikzpicture}                                                          
        \begin{axis} [                                                           
                ybar stacked,                                                    
                height = \axisdefaultheight,                                     
                width = \textwidth,                                              
                xlabel = Channel,                                                
                ylabel = Counts,                                                 
                ymin = 0,                                                        
                xmin = -5,                                                       
                xmax = 260,                                                      
                xtick pos = left,                                                
                axis on top,                                                     
            ]                                                                    
            % Vertical division of each Board [0-7]                              
            \addplot[                                                            
                ybar interval,                                                   
                x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-0.5},                            
                fill = black!20] table {data.txt};                               
            \addplot[                                                            
                ybar interval,                                                   
                x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-0.5},                            
                fill = black] table {data2.txt};                                 
        \end{axis}                                                               
    \end{tikzpicture}                                                            
\end{figure}                                                                     
\end{document}
```

For some reason the `y` value of the stacked bars seems to be correct, but the fill of the bars does not fill them properly. How can I both problems in my plot?

[image: Bad]

Comment: Maybe `\begin{axis}[ybar interval stacked, ...]` (and remove two `ybar interval` used in `\addplot[...]`.

Answer (score 1):

The most important point is to, as suggested by muzimuzhi Z
, [use `ybar interval stacked`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624108/stacked-ybar-interval#comment1558029_624108). However, it is then not so easy to use a `fill between` plot, at least it does not appear to be straightforward. However, you could just [use the `axis background`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413306) key to draw the shaded regions.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}                                                    
\usepackage[top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,left=2.75cm,right=2.75cm]{geometry}         
\usepackage{pgfplots}                                                            
\usetikzlibrary{calc}                                                            
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}                                                 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}                                                        
                                                                                 
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data.txt}                                                   
0 10000                                                                          
1 15000                                                                          
2 10000                                                                          
3 20000                                                                          
4 5000                                                                           
5 0                                                                              
\end{filecontents}                                                               
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data2.txt}                                                  
0 10000                                                                          
1 15000                                                                          
2 10000                                                                          
3 20000                                                                          
4 5000                                                                           
5 0                                                                              
\end{filecontents}                                                               
\begin{document}                                                                 
\begin{figure}[h]                                                                
    \centering                                                                   
    \begin{tikzpicture}                                                          
        \begin{axis} [                                                           
                ybar interval stacked,                                                    
                height = \axisdefaultheight,                                     
                width = \textwidth,                                              
                xlabel = Channel,                                                
                ylabel = Counts,                                                 
                ymin = 0,                                                        
                xmin = -5,                                                       
                xmax = 260,                                                      
                xtick pos = left,                                                
                axis on top,  
                axis background/.style={%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413306
                preaction={
                    path picture={
                        \path  (axis cs:0,0) coordinate (O) 
                         (path picture bounding box.north) coordinate (T)
                         foreach \x in {0,...,4} {(axis cs:64*\x-0.5,0) coordinate (x\x)}
                         (current axis.south east) coordinate (x5);                   
                        \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
                        {\ifodd\x\relax
                         \else
                         \fill[black!6] (x\x|-O) rectangle (x\the\numexpr\x+1\relax|-T);
                        \fi
                        \draw[black!6] (x\x|-O) -- (x\x|-T);}
                        }}}                                                   
            ]                                                                    
            \addplot[                                                            
                x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-0.5},                            
                fill = black!20] table {data.txt};                               
            \addplot[                                                            
                x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-0.5},                            
                fill = black] table {data2.txt};                                 
        \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}                                                            
\end{figure}                                                                     
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I still see the same problem as in my question. As you can see from your picture the bars are not properly stacked on top of each other; there is a random gap between them. Notice that the total `y` is correct, but it is not filled properly. There should be a continuous black line all the way down until the first bar, but there is not.

Comment: Well, yes, this appears to be an issue of `ybar interval stacked`, which you may want to report. (P.S. I am out of here, I do not see why I should waste my time with a bunch of aggressive people.)

Comment: What aggressive people? Did I miss a discussion in the comments? I didn't get any notifications for any activity. Ok, I will look into how to report such issues. Thanks